# What's the best way to preserve a Linked List between activities?

Tags: android

This is my problem, I have this two activities:

Activity A---->Activity B.

In activity "B" I creates a "LlinkedList of type ImageInformation.class" where Imageinformation.class have this values: ID, Name, Path, Size, Type.

So when I go back from "B" to "A" I know you can send back this linkedlist, but from activity "A" I can go to "A"----->"C" and from "C" ----->"D" and from "D"------->"E" then go back to the activity "A".

There is a way to preserve this linkedlist through all these activities?. Or I need to store the data in SQLite?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the singleton pattern to have a unique instance in your application, and call it from all your activities with `MySingleton.getInstance()`.
Although it is generally not a recommended and should be avoided when possible, it appears to be suitable for such case when you need a light in-memory shared object.

Comment: do I have to use getInstance() to get everything of my class? MySingleton.getInstance().method MySingleton.getInstance().variables how to just sayMySingleton.variable or MySingleton.method

Answer (score 1):

You can implement your list with a [parcelable](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html), and pass that around in the intent when you create your activities.

Comment: Even if it improves performances, no need to make it parcelable to make pass it through intents.

Comment: What about create a static linkedList?

Comment: that will cause the Activity class that contains the static linkedList not be able to be garbage collected since other Activity classes will be holding reference to it. In this case, parcelable and singleton as lukas suggested should both work.

Comment: Thanks I will use Singleton pattern.